# why my code doesn't work in chrome or FF

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

these 2 functions seems to be working only on IE. this is the code:

```
function onGridMembers(id,xml) {
    if (xml != "<Members/>" && ToHelpOrNotToHelp) {
        var domDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        domDoc.loadXML(xml);
        var helpHtml2 = "";
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "Dictionary.xml", true);
        xmlDictionary = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        xmlhttp.send();       
        helpHtml2 += xmlDictionary.selectSingleNode("Terms/Term[Key='" + domDoc.selectSingleNode("Members/Member/@UName").text + "']/Desc").text;
        alert(helpHtml2);           
    }
}



function onCommandClicked(nectoId, commandId, commnadCaption, xml)  {

    if (commandId == "ID223") {                // this one doesn't work in chrome
       window.open('file://server/Guide.docx'); 
    } else if (commandId == "ID225") {           // This one works in chrome
        window.open('http://server/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx');                        
    } else if (commandId == "ID227") {       // this one doesn't work in chrome
        getComponentById("vvv","ww").setMenuItemState("ID227", "Hidden");
        getComponentById("vvv","ww").setMenuItemState("ID226", "Enable");

        ToHelpOrNotToHelp = false;        
    } else if (commandId == "ID226") {     // this one doesn't work in chrome
        getComponentById("vvv","ww").setMenuItemState("ID226", "Hidden");
        getComponentById("vvv","ww").setMenuItemState("ID227", "Enable");

        ToHelpOrNotToHelp = true;
    }
}
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Uses IE-only ActiveX objects (as further hinted by `Microsoft.`), wonders why it doesn't work outside of IE...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the second code, but the first cannot work in other browsers than IE because you're using ActiveX, which is MS-Only.

The Firefox Error-Console usually gives useful information on why JS is not working.